# Derivative of $x^2e^{-x}$

Tags: derivatives

So I have to function $x^2e^{-x}$. Do I derivative that like $f' g+g' f$ or $f' g'$?
I'm not sure because it is derivative over x so if you can help me.

Comment: product rule: $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$

Comment: Note that $e^{-x}$ is a function inside function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have *multiplication*, use the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'.$

Any time you have one function *inside* another function (composition), use the chain rule.

In this case, you have $x^2$ *times* $e^{-x}$, so you use the product rule. $f(x) = x^2$, $g(x) = e^{-x}$. Can you manage from here?

Answer (score 1):

It is the product rule that you need. So with $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = e^{-x}$, you get the derivative of $f(x)g(x)$
$$f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x).
$$